# How to permanently make ffmpeg recognizable from bin/bash in macOS

Tags: bash, macos, ffmpeg, terminal, macos-sierra

I downloaded a zip for ffmpeg, because brew installation was not compatible with macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. After unzipping, the only file contained was ffmpeg, its icon is similar to the icon of the terminal. I want to get the terminal(which runs bin/bash $SHELL) to permanently recognise `ffmpeg` command.

If I type:

1. `echo export PATH="/Users/imac/Documents/ffmpeg:$PATH" > ~/.bashrc`
2. `source ~/.bashrc`
3. `ffmpeg`
   then the command `ffmpeg` is recognized, so everything is ok.

However if I exit the terminal and re-open it, or just restart the computer
`ffmpeg` gives as output `-bash: ffmpeg: command not found`. So I have to do every time steps 1 and 2 that were describe above.

4. Output of `cat .bashrc` :
   `export PATH=/Users/imac/Documents/ffmpeg:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin`
5. Output of `echo $PATH` :
   `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin`

**Note** that in step 4 `ffmpeg` appears(in the location I have it stored) whereas in step 5 `ffmpeg` is absent. Also I have little knowledge of bash and terminal, so if you can, please be explanatory in answers and/or comments. Thank you very much!

Comment: When you do `> ~/.bashrc` instead of `>> ~/.bashrc` you overwrite the file, losing all its previous contents. This is most certainly not what you wanted. Try to get that file back from a backup. If Macos doesn't read `~/.bashrc` on startup, it may be using `~/.bash_profile`. Add `source $HOME/.bashrc` to `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: @Robert thanks, I added `source $HOME/.bashrc` to `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: If anyone else needs it, I did:  1) `cd ~; nano .bash_profile`
                                                  2) paste in the last line `source $HOME/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. `cd ~; nano .bash_profile`
2. Copy and Paste *-in the bottom-* the path you want to add, as follows 
   `export PATH="<Replace with the path>:$PATH"`
3. Save settings

**Note:** `<...>` are meant to be replaced

E.g. for me it was: 
`export PATH="/Users/imac/Documents/ffmpeg:$PATH"`